# Set day of month to 1 for new user

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

my question is how to exclude day of month in MYSQL if value is null  or empty in database ?

so that i can use that 1 for the new employee i.e  when employee first time login for attendance then day of month start with 1 .

i want if daycount have null or empty then day of month start with 1,2,3...
weekend column is week of day working day and working column is total working of month

```
   <%

    Calendar cal  = Calendar.getInstance();     
    int day = cal.get(cal.DAY_OF_WEEK);     
    int days=day-1;//This is show day of week
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);        
    Date date13 = new Date();       
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTime(cal.getTime());
    cal2.setTime(date13);

    int numberOfDays = 0;
    while (cal1.before(cal2)) {
        if ((Calendar.SATURDAY != cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))&&(Calendar.SUNDAY != cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))) 
        {
            numberOfDays++;
          session.setAttribute("numberOfDays",numberOfDays);// This is show day of month
            cal1.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
        }else {
            cal1.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
        }

    }           

    %>
```

i want that if daycount is null or empty then day of week and day of month start with 1.I am facing problem that any employee join in mid date of month  like joining date is (19-03-2014) it is showing total working day 13 but i want it will be show 1.

```
   ResultSet rs1=st.executeQuery("select empid,empname,empdepart,date,SUM(daycount)weekend,tworking from "+user+"");
```

Comment: Not sure whether I am able to understand the problem. However, if you want conditions and null check then you should use COALESCE function of MySQL. Also, you may want to use if conditions as well. Go through the link http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php.

Comment: i have used calendar for exclude day of month but i want exclude day of month in mysql if table have null or empty then day of month start with 1

Comment: set a value in the DB and check for its occurrence if you find that then set it to 1 else other.

Comment: Very confusing question. Needs rewriting.

Comment: i hope you will understand my question

Comment: no one help me please give me idea