# How to redirect on login page after logout

Tags: java, jsp

I want to  when click on log out tab then redirect on login page after logout. This is not go on login page.

*Home.jsp*

```
<ul><li><a href="http://pushkalit.in/logout.jsp"> Logout</a></li></ul>
```

*logout.jsp*

```
<% try {

    if(session.getAttribute("Username") != null) {
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store");
        response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
        response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);
        session.invalidate();
        response.sendRedirect("http://pushkalit.in/hrlogin.jsp");
    }
    else {}
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    out.print(ex);
}
%>
```

Comment: Whenever the page is rendered,user will get his session invalidated irrespective of his clicking the Logout hyper link

Comment: hi Abhinav http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496903/set-day-of-month-to-1-for-new-user give me some idea how to do

Comment: Wait, did you get it to work? How? If it is working for you please close the answer

Comment: how to close the anser

Answer (score 1):

i think it would be easier if you just put the logout login inside  servlet instead of an jsp. And don't forget to do a

```
session.invalidate()
```

EDIT (further detail): something like this :

```
package com.my.package;

public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    request.getSession().invalidate();
    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.jsp");
  }
}
```

In your servlet.xml (you could also do it with an annotation) configure it like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>logoutServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.my.package.LogoutServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>logoutServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/logout</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And then finally your link goes to:

```
<a href="http://pushkalit.in/yourapplication/logout">Logout</a>
```

Comment: i will have to write on login page or log out page

Comment: An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /hrlogout.jsp
  void is an invalid type for the variable doGet

Comment: what i'm suggsting you is to write a servlet with the code provided and not to copy it inside your existing hrlogout.jsp

Comment: public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet{ doGet(...) {...} }

Comment: hi fGo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496903/set-day-of-month-to-1-for-new-user.please give me some idea how to do

Answer (score 0):

URL mapping in anchor tag seems to be wrong.

It is linked to `logout.jsp` but you have the redirect code in `Hrlogout.jsp`.

**Change**:

```
<a href="http://pushkalit.in/logout.jsp"> Logout</a>
```

**To**:

```
<a href="http://pushkalit.in/Hrlogout.jsp"> Logout</a>
```

Comment: What was happening after clicking link? Where did you get landed?

Comment: first you need to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018215/what-is-url-pattern-in-web-xml-and-how-to-configure-servlet and also, why is not working?

Comment: DeepakSingh: You need to understand configuring servlet mapping. Read @fGo's answer for more details

Comment: i have solved logout problem .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496903/set-day-of-month-to-1-for-new-user please help me how to do